# Change arrays to url format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js

```
<% for(var i=0; i < 1; i++) { %>
<a href="<%= related[i] %>"> <%= related[i] %> </a>
<% } %>
```

I need to change related[i] to url format (lowercase, add "-" instead a space, remove some !,/ and more)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 0):

```
<% for(var i=0; i < 1; i++) { %>
<a href="<%= related[i].toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, "-"); %>"> <%= related[i] %></a>
<% } %>
```

we can add .toLowerCase() and replace(/ /gi, "-") to change string to lowercase and add replace space with "-"

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.